# Laravel - Eloquent "with"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-6

tengo un modelo "Form" y otro "Answers", la relación es 1 a N

El modelo **form** tiene los campos : uuid y name
El modelo **Answers** tiene los campos : uuid , title , form_id y **user_id**

A nivel de BBDD tengo algo como esto

**Form**
id : 1, uuid : x1 , name  form-ejemplo-1
id : 2, uuid : x2 , name  form-ejemplo-2

**Answers**
uuid : t1 , title : title1 , form_id : 1 , user_id : 1
**uuid : t1 , title : title1 , form_id : 1 , user_id : 2**
uuid : t1 , title : title1 , form_id : 2 , user_id : 1
uuid : t1 , title : title1 , form_id : 2 , user_id : 1

Lo que intento obtener es todos los forms que tienen respuestas del user_id = 1, por lo tanto serian los registros anteriores 1, 3 y 4 (el 2 no)

Y para ello intento hacerlo de esta forma con eloquent, pero me devuelve los 4 , no me filtra por user_id = 1

```
    $user = Auth::user();

    $user_id = $user->id;

    $forms = Form::where('id','>=',0)->with('answers')
        ->whereHas('answers', function ($query) use ($user_id) {
             $query->where('user_id', $user_id);
        })->get();
```

Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Después de darle vueltas lo he sacado de esta manera.

```
    $constraint = function ($query) {
        $query->where('user_id', auth()->id());
    };

    $forms = Form::where('id','>=',0)
        ->with(['answers' => $constraint])
        ->whereHas('answers', $constraint)
        ->get();

    return response()->json($forms, 200);
```

Gracias